# How to overload the << operator to add elements to a vector using a template function? (c++)

Tags: c++, templates, vector, operators, overloading

I'm working on a project for school and my teacher wants us to overload the "<<" operator so that it adds elements to a vector. He also wants us to use a template so it can be used for any type of element.

Here is my header file code:

```
template<typename T>
vector<T>& operator<<(vector<T>& v, const T element) {
    v.push_back(element);
    return v;
}
```

And here is what I'm trying to run:

```
v1 << "Atlanta" << "Dallas" << "Chicago" << "Boston" << "Denver";
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error C2676: binary '<<': 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Can anyone help me as to why this isn't working? I'm using the latest version of visual studio and I've properly added my files to the solution and everything. It was working for a little when I replaced "const T element" with "const string element" for a while but once I added the implementation again it didn't work. Thanks for the advice.

EDIT: Thank you for the help, here is the answer that ending up working for me:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
vector<T>& operator<<(vector<T>& v, const U& element) {
    v.push_back(element);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of ```v1```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals like `"Atlanta"` are not of type `std::string` (they're arrays of `char`), but your function requires the vector element type and the operator right-hand argument type to be the same type.

If you allow the right-hand argument type to be different, then it works, e.g.:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& v, U&& element) {
    v.emplace_back(std::forward<U>(element));
    return v;
}
```

Note that I move the argument into the vector to avoid a needless deep copy if e.g. an `std::string` is passed in by value.

**Edit:** changed to use `emplace_back` as discussed in comments

Comment: Almost perfect:
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& v, U&& element) {
    v.push_back(std::forward<U>(element));
    return v;
}
using U&& in combination with std::forward<U> can also move the parameter directly into the vector (using perfect argument forwarding)

Comment: would you mind to update your post to use perfect argument forwarding?

Comment: @kiloalphaindia If you think it's that important, you should submit your own answer (as you have done). If the answerer doesn't edit their answer to reflect what you mentioned in the comments, there's no reason to expect them to do so; just make your own answer

Comment: The problem with this answer is it makes a full copy of the element before moving it into the vector.  Possibly this can be elided if an rvalue is passed in, but for ordinary lvalues that are not cheap to move, it ends up making a needless copy and incurs the cost twice.  One into element, then another into the vector.  As this is supposed to be _generic_ code, one should not assume to know if the types used are efficient to move or not, and perfect forwarding is better.

Answer (score 4):

To add to [the solution by emlai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50241781), using perfect argument forwarding can be better:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& v, U&& element) {
    v.emplace_back(std::forward<U>(element));
    return v;
}
```

In contrast to the solution using `std::move` by @emlai this one uses perfect argument forwarding, which can directly move the object into the vector, rather than passing it by value.

**Edit:** changed to use emplace_back as discussed in comments

Comment: I suppose a note on the possible use of emplace_back, instead of push_back, would be in order.

Comment: That is not the same, because emplace would construct an object in place, while in our case the object is already constructed by the caller and should be moved into the vector if possible. - thinking it over... it is the same, because it would call the move constructor...

Comment: OP is working with a vector of strings and is passing char arrays at the call site, so the second argument is not a string. Thus, no string has been created before the argument is passed to push_back.

Comment: @Jonas Correct, but the operator will be applied to any type, so best to make int work well for these too.

Comment: So for char arrays emplace_back avoids a move. If it is an rvalue string then we might as well construct it in-place with emplace_back and move-constructor, and the same logic follows for an lvalue string, expect we the of course use a copy-constructor. When would you consider push_back the right choice?

Comment: @Jonas beattyful! Of cause push_back expects an element type parameter while the actual questions is not passing in an object of value type, therefore emplace_back is indeed better - updating answer

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
v1 << "Atlanta" << "Dallas" << "Chicago" << "Boston" << "Denver";
```

the parameter `T` is not deduced to `std::string`. It is deduced to `‘const char [8]` for `"Atlanta"`. The types for the other arguments will be deduced similarly.

Change the function so that the type of element is deduced from the `std::vector`.

```
template<typename Vector>
Vector& operator<<(Vector& v, typename Vector::value_type const& element) {
    v.push_back(element);
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would compile if the type of the vector elements and the arguments to the operator match:

```
std::vector<const char*> v1;
v1 << "Atlanta" << "Dallas" << "Chicago" << "Boston" << "Denver";
```

Likewise using `std::string` literals would also work for a vector of `std::string`s:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::vector<std::string> v1;
v1 << "Atlanta"s << "Dallas"s << "Chicago"s << "Boston"s << "Denver"s;
```

It is possible to get the `char` arrays directly into the `std::string` elements by adding another template:

```
//this template will accept the const char array and construct a string
template<class T, class S,  size_t N>
std::vector<S>& operator<<(std::vector<S>& v, const T(& arr)[N]) 
{
    v.push_back({std::begin(arr), std::end(arr)});
    //v.push_back(arr); // would also work for char
    return v;
}
```